Почему bash скрипт не запускается при запуске системы в LInux Mint? (cron)
У меня есть bash-скрипт fix_caps.sh:
#!/bin/bash
xkbcomp /etc/myxkbmap $DISPLAY

Он находится по пути: /home/asl/.fix_caps.sh и я пытаюсь его запустить через crontab -e. Я прописал там эту команду @reboot /home/asl/.fix_caps.sh и перезагрузил системы что бы проверить работу скрипта, но он не запустился. А если я сам запущу этот скрипт нажав по нему ЛКМ и нажав на run, то он заработает. Из-за чего в cron не сработало ?

Он, наверное запустился, но при запуске из cron нет переменной DISPLAY. На стадии reboot и иксов-то ещё нет наверное

попробуй доразобраться в xprofile или накрайняк xdg-autostart

крон не подходит для такого

@eri Вот такая инструкция сойдет:


Сперва создаю файл с расширением .desktop


Потом вставлю туда это:


Type=Application
Name=MyScript
Exec=/путь/к/вашему/скрипту.sh
Terminal=false```

4) Потом перемещу файл в директорию ~/.config/autostart/, если он предназначен для запуска при входе в систему для текущего пользователя, или /etc/xdg/autostart/, если он должен быть запущен для всех пользователей.
